# Leaflet Draw Plugin:: how to find latlng of polyline and save them to Database

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have fetched latlng of polyline using function `getLatlngs()`. Latlng are saved in database in format like `"LatLng(-37.76949, 175.26481),LatLng(-37.77211, 175.26884),LatLng(-37.77323, 175.26532)"`.

```
$query = "Select * from geofence where geo_type=3";
$result = pg_exec($db_handle,$query);
if($result) {
for($row = 0; $row < pg_numrows($result); $row++){
    $fence_id   = pg_result($result,$row,'geo_id');
    $fence_nam  = strtoupper(pg_result($result,$row,'geo_name'));
    $fence_typ  = pg_result($result,$row,'geo_type');
    $fence_coord    = pg_result($result,$row,'geo_coord');

?>
line<? echo $fence_id; ?> = new L.Polyline([new L.<? echo $fence_coord ?>).addTo(map);
<?      
    }
}

?>
}
```

How to draw these latlng on map? I have also used php split method to split latlngs but no success.

Comment: What code do you have on client? Do you have JS errors on client? I think that `new L.Polyline([new L.<? echo $fence_coord ?>).addTo(map);` will implemented as `new L.Polyline([new L.LatLng(-37.76949, 175.26481),LatLng(-37.77211, 175.26884),LatLng(-37.77323, 175.26532)).addTo(map);` and this is not valid js because you didn't close array ']' and didn't have `new L.` before each point. I advice you store points as `"[-37.76949, 175.26481],[-37.77211, 175.26884],[-37.77323, 175.26532]"`.

Comment: yes, you are right. but i have stored lat long in the format " -37.05518, 177.49512: -35.06597, 177.49512: -35.06597, 180.08789: -37.05518, 180.08789". then i am using PHP split function like this: rectangle<? echo $fence_id; ?> = new L.rectangle([
<?php
 $a = array();
 $a = split(":",$fence_coord);
 for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
  echo "[".$a[$i]."],";
 }
?>],{color:"#738DEA",weight:4}).addTo(map);

Comment: you have different information in question and comment. Can you update your question for actual information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I used javascript function like this

function splitfunc(str){
    var a = ""+str;
    var b= replaceAll(/\)\,/g,":",a);
    var c= replaceAll(/LatLng\(/g," ",b);
    var d= replaceAll(/\)/g," ",c);
    return d;
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {       
    return str.replace(find, replace);
}

Using these functions you can save Lat Long in any format
```